# Windows 7 KSOD On Login

Tags: windows

For those that are unaware, KSOD means blacK Screen of Death. Essentially, when windows starts my computer shows only the cursor and a black screen. It seems like any and all shell elements are disabled (or perhaps not started). I have seen a number of these questions asked, none of which have matched my situation.

1. CTRL + ALT + ... does not respond
2. Restarting in safe mode, results in the same KSOD
3. sfc /scannow seems to have no effect when typed at the command prompt that is accessed using the recovery tools via the install disk
4. There are no restore points (System Restore is turned off)
5. "Last Known Good configuration" was/is not available in the startup recovery list
6. Left the computer on in KSOD state for approx 7 hours (went to sleep). Did not self-resolve.

---

### Update to item 3:

sfc /scannow reports: There is a system repair pending which requires reboot to complete. Restart Windows and run sfc again.

However, Windows does not restart past KSOD.

---

### Update to item 3 as per Soandos comment re: /offbootdir

sfc /scannow /offbotdir=e:\ /windir=e:\windows

"Windows resource protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them. Details are included in the CBS.log..."

In reviewing the CBS.log, there's a) too much information and far too many "failures" that could be false positives as to the root of my problem.

---

Help and comments are most appreciated

Comment: How about `sfc` with the offbootdir and offwindir flags set?

Comment: Just for completeness sake, what version of windows? Could you give any details on what you'd done previously?

Comment: Windows 7 64-bit pro. Soandos, I'll try that

Comment: Journeyman Geek, I havent tried anything save those options listed in 1,2,3 above. Well, other than performing Dell hardware tests as a JIC measure.

Comment: Have you tried any of the windows repair options? Disk scans, etc?

Comment: "Start up repair" and Dell specific disk/hardware checks. No errors reported from a hardware perspective.

Comment: This sounds similar to something I've seen before: http://superuser.com/questions/328902/system-restore-error-0x490-winvista - a corrupted Windows update. Do you have anything you can restore from?

Comment: @NateKoppenhaver No and not likely, both system restore and windows update are turned off on this machine.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen the "system repair pending" made me think it might be from an update. Have you installed any drivers or updated anything recently?

Comment: @NateKoppenhaver the system had not been restarted for nearly a month. I did not install any new drivers with the exception of PnP for some storage devices (USB Keys/Drives). I've updated a significant amount of software on the system related to statistical programming but I feel that is exigent to this problem.

Comment: I've also updated the question with some of the recommendations from the comments and their results.

Comment: Did you examine the CBS.log file? What did it say? I don't know about you but this is quickly getting to the point where I would just stick the drive in another PC, pull my personal files off of it and reinstall Windows.

Comment: @allquixotic that's exactly what I'm doing right now (fresh install). And no, the CBS file is less than explanatory and hundreds of thousands of lines long, I didn't waste any time trying to decipher it.

Comment: I'm wondering, how much RAM does the machine have? The system will attempt to write the contents of the `pagefile.sys` after a crash into a memory dump. In case your system is configured for a full dump this can take ages, depending on the amount of RAM (and consequently the size of the `pagefile.sys`).

Comment: @0xC0000022L 16GB of RAM. I use this computer for statistical computing, it has reasonably hefty specs. In any case, appreciate the continued support - but I'm in process of moving my data over and doing a fresh install of windows.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this/similar issue and in most cases, the system would return to normal after many minutes.  How long have you waited? One case I had took over 45 minutes.  You mentioned storage dvices specifically so here is what I discovered.

I found that a USB DVD-R that was connected caused this issue.  Unplug and all was well.  Same thing with a  USB key on a different system.

Never discoverd the real "why" but the fix was to unplug a device.  Once booted, all was well and the device could be reconnected.

BTW, have you tried Last Known Good?

Comment: Thanks David. I left it on for a few hours (approx 7) over night on the KSOD. I tried all possible permutations of connecting and disconnecting peripheral devices. Last Known Good was not available at the selection prompt.