# Black screen after windows welcome screen

Tags: boot

I've started to get my laptop stopping on a black screen after the windows welcome screen. 
I have to hit the power button to turn off and try again or start in safe mode before eventually it powers on. When running Windows 7 ''check for performance issues'' i get a message about too many start up programs, but i dont seem to have hardly any listed in its''start up'' list when i check with CCleaner, and i've removed a few in the past. I do though have around 30 programs/icons on my desktop, including 3 web browers,adobe reader,time freeze,c cleaner,Mword,excel,pshop,etc. Apart from that i dont have anything thats remotely resource hungry. Its an ACer Aspire one 2gb. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Possibly related: http://superuser.com/questions/447414/windows-7-ksod-on-login

Comment: Is there a mouse pointer on that black screen?

Answer (score 0):

Go to run (windows key + R) > type msconfig > Startup (tab)  **Check here and make sure there is nothing you don't want starting up at startup**

Also this "black screen" is this a command prompt window? if so hit Ctrl+C and it should abort

Comment: Thanks for help.No its just a completely black empty screen. On mscofig ,do i need the gfxserviceinstall and tvncontrol to run on startup? tnx

Comment: I use ToolWizTimefreeze all the time aswell. I only have 3 items listed under startup in msconfig and the other is my AV.TNX.

Comment: In ''services'' on msconfig i have quite a few programs running that i dont really use. Like adobe acrobat update service, and an apple one which i guess was from when i had safari,since uninstalled safari. Will unchecking any of these simply stop them running but i can still use on demand?

Comment: Everything in startup can be stopped, as for services these are things that will run "quietly" in the background until called - Adobe is an example of a company who abuses this with constant update notification.

Comment: Start by stopping everything you can spare to stop then use your pc - evaluate if anything needs to be started again and start as needed. It's a long process but will give the best results

Comment: Tnx.I'll try that.On running windows ''trouble shooter'' it keeps on giving the following issue ;

''This computer is set up to automatically run programs at start up''
Will things like adobe reader, internet explorer all try to load at startup ? I never use IE, occasionally use firefox. Mostly use Chrome and another browser. So come to think of it i have 4 browsers. Thanks

Comment: The next suggestion is to do a clean install of windows. try not to restore from the acer discs as you will still get bloatware such as gfxserviceinstall